# Magento PHP Code escaping at a href, how to make it not escape?

Tags: php, html, magento

I have the following PHP Code in Magento. It keeps escaping at the a href, but I don't want it to. Any way to prevent this? The entire variable must stay in tact, as it gets passed via API to a 3rd party service.

[This is what shows instead; the a href and everything afterwards gets completely cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8cSg.png)

[This is what shows in PHP storm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHm0d.png)

```
$productId = $item->getProductId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$specialtype = $product->getAttributeText('specialproduct');
if(in_array($specialtype, array('garminpilot','garminpilotpro','garminpilotpremium','garmintrainer'))) {
    //$specialproductmsg = 'You have ordered an online course. Please visit http://www.example.com/onlinecourse to view your online course.';
    $itunesLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/garmin-pilot/";
    $androidLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details";
    $garminLink = "https://pilot.garmin.com";
    $specialproductmsg = '
    <div>
        <div><p>Redemption Code: <strong></strong></p></div>
        <h4>How to use your Garmin Pilot App</h4>
        <ol>
            <li>Download the free app from the <a href="'.$itunesLink.'">App Store</a> or <a href="'.$androidLink.'">Google Play</a>.</li>
            <li>In the app, select Home, then Settings, then Subscriptions</li>
            <li>Create a new login and password</li>
            <li>
                On your computer, go to the <a href="'.$garminLink.'" target="_blank">Garmin Pilot website</a> and enter your redemption code.
            </li>
            <li>Enter the username and password you created in the app</li>
        </ol>
    </div>';

}
else {
    $specialproductmsg = ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` instead of `"` when referencing links in PHP.

So in your case, use `<a href='$itunesLink'>App Store</a>`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, either. Same result both ways; using ' or ". Any other ideas?

Comment: @JamesAnderson Is the variable already defined as a string? I would guess so since it's a link to iTunes, try removing the `'` completely, and just have `<a href=$itunesLink>App Store</a>`

Comment: Hmm, that did not work, either. Starting to wonder if it's the 3rd party I'm sending the data to, stripping out the a href for some reason. Anything else I could do, to rule that out?

Comment: Well if your error is about the escaping character, I don't think that would have anything to do with it. Try this. At the beginning of `$specialproductmsg` You've got `'`, change that to a `"` and change the closing one as well. Then on the href, remove the `"` and only use `'`. So it should look like `$specialproductmsg = "` and `<a href='$itunesLink'>App Store</a>`

Comment: Also, whatever you change on the `href`, do the same for the other `href`'s within that variable, which is `$androidLink` and `$garminLink`